# Subprocess doesn't work as expected with Apache Airflow

Tags: python, subprocess, airflow

I've been testing subprocess for template files in order to understand how this module works and I did many tests calling files from within the same directory as the "main" file and calling files from different directories and it all go well.

When trying to integrate this module on a Airflow system, subprocess can never get the file that I am searching for and it doesn't give any errors.
On this particular situation, I'm trying to call the "test.py" script from the "simple_dag.py" file. However, i can't seem to understand why it doesn't execute the method.

Did you ever had problemas running subprocess within an airflow "environment"? Do you have any idea how can I fix this problem?
Thank you.

Here is the code of the files:

[To see the code click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHB69.png)

Comment: It's not convenient to type your code from the screenshot. Please paste it with proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

In your pythonOperator try `python_callable = _my_name()`